# Query using ILIKE with IN

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

Is it possible to run a query using ILIKE with the IN function? For example:

```
SELECT store_names
FROM stores
WHERE states ILIKE IN (SELECT location
                       FROM   locations
                       WHERE  stateID = 1)
```

I want to run the results returned from the nested query through the ILIKE function. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can be simpler:

```sql
SELECT s.store_names, l.location
FROM   stores s
JOIN   locations l ON s.states ILIKE l.location
WHERE  l.stateid = 1
```

You can check the resulting query plan with [`EXPLAIN ANALYZE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html).

You may need to [add leading and trailing `%`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE) to get partial matches:

```
... ON s.states ILIKE ('%' || l.location || '%')
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT store_names
FROM stores
WHERE states ILIKE any (SELECT location
FROM   locations
WHERE  stateID = 1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).